# How to set up client certificate validation in mongodb SSL

Tags: ssl

I have written below code to implement client certification validation in SSL in mongodb. But the below code throws " 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".

String filename = "C://mongodb-cert.cert";

clientSettings.UseSsl = connectInfo.EnableSSL;

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(filename);

clientSettings.SslSettings.ClientCertificates = new List(){cert};

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( clientSettings );

Could anyone please look at the code and let me know what is causing the exception to be thrown from the code.

Thanks in advance.

--Vibhu

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your filename?

```
String filename = "C://mongodb-cert.cert";
```

Should possibly be:

```
String filename = "C:\\mongodb-cert.cert";
```

Note the backslashes `\\` instead of forward-slashes `//`